# JavaScript alert function from php

Tags: javascript, php

I am attempting to call a JavaScript function from php code that I have written. I am trying to do it in the following manner, to no avail:

```
echo "<script>$('#myButton').click(function() { alert("Hello World"); });</script>"
```

I have seen suggestions that seem to point that the above way is the way to do it, but it is not working for me. Can someone assist? Thanks!

Comment: Escape your double quotes or use single quotes instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the " before Hello World closes the string. Use backslashes or '.

```
echo "<script>$('#myButton').click(function() { alert(\"Hello World\"); });</script>"
```

Or:

```
echo "<script>$('#myButton').click(function() { alert('Hello World'); });</script>"
```

Or, just forget about the string by exiting php. Note that while out of php mode your if statements and whatnot still work:

```
?>
<script>$('#myButton').click(function() { alert("Hello World"); });</script>
<?php
```

Also, if you don't want it too look like a mess, you can use the [alternate control structure syntax](http://php.net/alternative_syntax)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider just going out of PHP mode, so that you don't have to worry about single vs double quotes at all:

```
?>
<script>
$('#myButton').click(function() { alert("Hello World"); });
</script>
<?php
```

Alternatively, use [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc):

```
echo <<<'HTML'
<script>
$('#myButton').click(function() { alert("Hello World"); });
</script>
HTML;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
echo "<script>$('#myButton').click(function() { alert(\"Hello World\"); });</script>";
```